# QGIS does not load the data

Tags: qgis

I am getting an error when I am trying to add a layer to the QGIS.
The error message says invalid data source.

I uninstalled and reinstalled the application. I am using a Mac and the build is 3.16 (Hannover).

Comment: What is the type of your data source? Is it a shapefile? How did you export the data?

Comment: .shp file was used to add a layer. I was able to do this on the same machine yesterday and not today.